# PEAR and pirum and package.xml

Tags: php, package, pear, channel

Not terribly familiar with any inner workings of PEAR.  But I have installed pirum onto a folder on my host to distribute Magento Extensions outside of Magento Connect.
Basically the channel is set up and I can see it with channel-discover.
When I try to add my package which lets say is **Package-1.0.0.tgz**. I get 
`The PEAR package does not have a package.xml file. (InvalidArgumentException, 0)`
There is a package.xml inside the tar...I put the same package.xml in the same directory as **Package-1.0.0.tgz** that I'm trying to add.  But it just errors out.
I'm really at a loss to what I'm doing wrong but I imagine its my lack of knowledge of packaging pear extensions.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: how did you create the package? The best way is to run "pear package" in your package directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the package with "pear package", do not targz it yourself.